# Contador de tareas javascripts

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenos dias chicos tengo una consulta quiero actualmente tener un contador en mi pagina que le permita hacer un conteo de cada operacion que hace y lleve su conteo y cuando este listo le de enviar. pero no encuentro como capturar el numero me envia el campo vacio ejemplo clickea 5 veces lo envia vacio y no el numero 5 agradecere cualquier apoyo

```js
var clicks=0;
function clickME() {
clicks += 1;
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
}
function clickME2() {
if (clicks>0) clicks -= 1;
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
}
```

```html
<h4 type="text" id="clicks">0</h4>
<div class="sumar" onClick="clickME()";>Sumar</div>
<div class="restar" onClick="clickME2();">Restar</div>






                      <button type="submit" id="bot" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Enviar</button>
```

actualmente muestro el conteo en un h4 una etiqueta ya que cuando intento capturarlo en el input me envia el campo vacio quizas sea algo sencillo de enviar pero yo no encuentro como porque es la primera vez que uso un contador.

```
  <tr>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <div id="#">0</div>
     </span>
    <td>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="restar" onClick="clickME2();" type="button">-</button>
      </span>
      <input
        type="number"
        style="width:50px;text-align: center;"
        id="clicks"
        class="form-control"
        value="1"
        min="1"
      />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="sumar" onClick="clickME()"; type="button">+</button>
      </span>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
```

ahora si vez la pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde esta el 11 es donde uso un div o un p o un h4 cualquiera y el codigo me funciona pero si intento usar el input ty darle el id que uso para mostrar datos. no me sube o baja nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si utilizas la etiqueta `<input>` cuando le pones el valor, tienes que utilizar la función `.value` en vez de `.innerHTML`

```
function clickME() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").value = clicks;
}
function clickME2() {
    if (clicks > 0) clicks -= 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").value = clicks;
}
```

Comment: Gracias maidagan exactamente lo que buscaba agradecido.